# Using date utility on Linux and AIX

Tags: linux, shell, aix

To verify a valid date I use the command line below:

```shell
date -d "${DATE}" "+%Y/%m/%d" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

It works perfectly under Cygwin, but not in my test environment.
Here's some information about my test environment:

```
uname -a
AIX 152101a07e 3 5 00CDE2314C00
```

Using the command line:

```
echo $?
```

The result is always 1, even if the date is valid.

Do you have any idea why this test fails?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What's the value of `$DATE`? What are you expecting the result to be?

Comment: It gives me always wrong (1)  <br/>
date -d "20131231" "+%Y/%m/%d" > /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: What do you mean? You're redirecting all the output to `/dev/null`, where do you see `(1)`?

Comment: I use echo $? to see the result

Comment: Would be nice if you put that in the question.

Comment: It seems to be working correctly. `20131231` is not a valid date, so it returns a non-zero exit code.

Comment: stopping redirect to `/dev/null` to see the error message.

Comment: The error is  <br/>   
date: illegal option -- d
Usage: date [-u] [+Field Descriptors]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, your two environments are not running the same version of `date`. You should check the `man` page for `date` in your new environment (run `man date`). On my machine (OS X), the `-d` option is used for setting daylight savings time.

For example, the following works for *me*:

```
date -j -f "%Y/%m/%d" "2014/07/09" > /dev/null 2>&1
echo $?  # 0

date -j -f "%Y/%m/%d" "2014.07.09" > /dev/null 2>&1
echo $?  # 1
```

`-j` tells it to not try to set my system date. `-f` means to use the specified format.

Yours may be different, but you can find out the details by reading the manual.